# Converted to decimal does not insert

Tags: mysql

can anybody tell me why this (line 3) is not working?

```
create table myTable ( myDecimal  decimal );

select convert('', decimal(5,2)) as myValue;

insert into myTable (myDecimal) select convert('', decimal(5,2)) as myValue;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not 100% sure about MySQL, but in MS SQL if you don't specify the precision when you create a decimal column you get 0 decimal places.

Comment: What is error message? What is your server version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect decimal (integer) value: ' ' mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037288/incorrect-decimal-integer-value-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table myTable ( myDecimal  decimal );

select convert('', decimal(5,2)) as myValue;


SET SESSION SQL_MODE = '';
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (MYDECIMAL) SELECT CONVERT('', DECIMAL(5,2)) AS MYVALUE;
```

It's due to strict SQL_MODE mode.

You can check at this **[STRICT_SQL_MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)**.

Try above query.

Comment: Thanks Sagar. Your statement doesn´t work for me, but INSERT IGNORE INTO MYTABLE (MYDECIMAL) SELECT CONVERT('', DECIMAL(5,2)) AS MYVALUE; do the trick! Maybe, I´m still confused why original does not work? I´m convert to decimal first, so I´m no inserting blank string.