# How to Suppress Warnings in MariaDB for 'Incorrect decimal value'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to do a bulk data upload into a MariaDB database. The data file has over 3M records. When the SQL runs the `LOAD DATA INFILE` (see below) statement, I get over 9600 warnings where there were problems when the data was inserted, most of them for `Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'xxx' at row yyy`.  The `LOAD DATA` statement is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Path to/Data File.txt'
    INTO TABLE xyz
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I tried the suggestion in "[Incorrect decimal (integer) value: ' ' mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037288/incorrect-decimal-integer-value-mysql)"
to use `SET SESSION sql_mode = ''` at the beginning of the script, but it has no effect.

As I see it, the fact that no value is being inserted into the affected columns is NOT an error and does not warrant a Warning.

I need to see the things that really ARE wrong, but all these Warnings are overwhelming me with garbage, and the important stuff is getting lost in all the noise. I've been searching for several days, but have found no solution -- How can I suppress Warnings for this issue?

Comment: Let's see the line in question.  And the `LOAD DATA` statement.

Comment: @Rick - See edit.

Comment: And a sample line with the column indicated?

Comment: @Rick - I can't show the client's data, but the columns of the records in question will simply have 2 consecutive tab (\t) characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA ...
    INTO (a, b, ..., @d, ...)
    SET d = IF (@d = '', 0, @d)
```

That is, load the column as a string into an `@variable` (`@d`), then decide what to do with the 'bad' string as you put it into the actual column (`d`)

Comment: The source data file has over 100 columns, and if I understand "user-defined variables", I would have to do that for every column that could result in a Warning being raised for this issue, correct?  Also, if there is no value to insert for one of these columns, a `NULL` value would have to be used (any other value, including a zero could be interpreted as a valid entry, which would in fact be incorrect).  Wouldn't inserting a value of `NULL` result in the same error?

Comment: If the column is declared `NULL` (as opposed to `NOT NULL`), the go ahead and put NULL in:  `SET d = IF(@d = '', NULL, @d)`.  With the `SETs` you have a lot of control over "fixing" the incoming data.  And, yes, it might be 100 @variables and 100 assignments in the `SET` clause of `LOAD DATA`.  Tedious, but a one-time task.

Comment: Ok, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Just to close out this unresolved question: It turned out that Windows path specs (w-backslashes) in 1 column were being interpreted as escape chars & wreaking havoc with the import by shifting the columns & trying to put `Null` values in columns that don't allow them.  Once the backslashes were addressed, the import worked correctly, making this solution unnecessary.  Thanks anyway for your assistance.